# Debugging Django App Installation

Tags: python, django

I've installed a Django application on a new host, but the runserver fails.  The first HTTP hit get the error "Import by filename is not supported."

The final error reads:

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
```

where the value of name is '/webcode/urls/urls'.  This is the value of ROOT_URLCONF.

This does work on the development host.  Both boxes are running Django 1.1.1, but the development is running Python 2.5.2, and the new box 2.6.5.

Neither has DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE; the settings.py file is in the same directory as manage.py.  The new host does have PYTHONPATH set to the directory holding the Django application, and my Django unit tests are passing, though none of these hits the urls.

I've tried switching the value of ROOT_URLCONF to a dotted module reference, but all permutations fail.

Any suggestions for how I can go about debugging this?

ANSWERED:
Fixed by changing line to

```
ROOT_URLCONF='webcode.urls.urls'
```

I'd previously been setting the value without the quotation marks, as if it were a Python reference rather than a string.

Answer (score 1):

Simple things to check first for Django: file permissions, MEDIA.ROOT, urls.py, ROOT_URLCONF in settings_local.py

Comment: File permissions for urls/ and its __init__.py and urls.py are the same on both.  MEDIA_ROOT looks right on new box.  I don't have a settings_local.py file, but do think the problem could be in ROOT_URLCONF in settings.py.

Comment: Try ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls' which should be the default but isn't always set.

Comment: Didn't work, but did generate a new error message ('no module named urls'.  So I guessed at 'ROOT_URLCONF=webcode.urls.urls' and, hey presto, she works!  Thanks for the hint.